# Screen flashing black just after booting

Tags: boot, 14.04, flash, screen, log

I've just been noticing, after updating to Ubuntu 14.04 that my screen flashes black at the log in screen. only for a quick second - but kinda weird seeing as it hadn't happened before. It only ever happens the once. It then goes on as normal

Anyone else get this? is it even a problem? Lol. I've just never experienced it before. I was thinking it could just be the screen calibrating or something.

I have a Samsung r730, 8GB RAM, i3 processor, 128gb samsung 840 pro ssd.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A black screen when booting is not something you should care about (if it's not too long, obviously). Myself, I have a screen showing like a ... mixed rainbow when booting, just a graphic driver thing.